# what is the return value of this recursive code means?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, tree

I'm not able to understand this kind of recursive code, what can I do to understand such functions. Can you help me explain what this function does (an example would help a lot).

```
typedef struct node* Nodeptr;
typedef struct node{
    int key;
    Nodeptr left,right;
}Node;
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to provide the code in text, not as an image. You might want to read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: This code could make sense if the structure supplied is a binary tree and the condition `t->left == t->right` is only true when both are `NULL`. Is this the case?

Comment: If it is the case, can you deduce what it is returning for the leaf node? Can you deduce what it will return for a non-leaf node?

Comment: StackOverflow is a successful community in part because the asker is expected to explain *precisely* what their problem is. These types of questions are useful to the community as a whole and any other readers that may encounter your problem in the future. If we had 20M questions that said "Help I don't understand," this is not only difficult to provide a useful answer, but also difficult for others to benefit.

Comment: It is an unusual function to ask a student new to trees to reverse engineer. It seems to be computing the sum of the keys in all the nodes on the path from the root to a leaf that has the greatest such sum. The return value is the first node on that path.

Comment: @WillNess: I meant the node from the root, but I was wrong. It returns a pointer to the leaf node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal rule for interpreting functions. Understanding what they do, when they are not documented, requires experience.

In the case of a recursive function, we can try building some understanding from the base case of the function and working up from there. The base case, or cases, is the one in which the function does not call itself: It produces an answer directly, without recursion. In this function, there are two base cases. The first is:

```
if (!t)
    return NULL;
```

This is a trivial case: If the function is passed a null pointer, it returns a null pointer and does not change `*a`.

The other is:

```
if (t->left == t->right)
{
    *a = t->key;
    return t;
}
```

As [Eugene sh. notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379376/how-can-i-understand-this-recursive-code-in-c#comment120848309_68379376), this is an obfuscated test for a leaf node: `t->left == t->right` is never true in a proper binary tree if either `left` or `right` points to another node. It is true when and only when both `left` and `right` are null pointers, so this is a leaf node (it does not have any children).

So, for a leaf node, the function returns the node (`t`) and sets `*a` to the value of its key.

Then we have the recursive case:

```
x = f(t->left, &b);
y = f(t->right, &c);
*a = b>c ? b+t->key : c+t->key;
return b>c ? x : y;
```

The first two lines are common for a recursive function on a binary tree: We apply the function to the left subtree and to the right subtree. (Note that if the passed pointer is null, `b` or `c` (whichever was passed) is not changed (due to the trivial base case above), so it remains at its initialized value, zero.)

Then `*a = b>c ? b+t->key : c+t->key;` adds `t-key` to the greater of `b` or `c` and sets `*a` to the sum. The value from the other subtree is ignored. Thus, we are computing some sort of maximum.

Then `return b>c ? x : y;` returns the pointer to the node whose value we used. Thus, it returns some indication of where we got the maximum from.

Now we know what the tree does with one level of subtrees under it: It computes the value of the current key plus the maximum of the keys under it and puts that sum in `*a`. It returns a pointer to the leaf node we got the value from.

From that, we can figure out what it does with two levels of subtrees: It computes the value of the current key plus the maximum from the two calls it makes. So it is choosing the maximum sum from two paths. And it returns the pointer associated with the sum it chose, which started as a pointer to a leaf node. So the function always returns a pointer to the leaf node at the end of the path being used.

Overall, the function computes the greatest sum along any path from the root to a leaf and puts that in `*a`. It returns a pointer to the leaf at the end of the path.

Note the above assumes `key` is non-negative. If some `key` values are negative, they may be overridden by zero values computed for empty subtrees.

Comment: many thanks for the effort and for the great explination .